# Spring & kotlin : What is the difference between constructor and lateinit injection?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I had a problem with my application using spring an kotlin. At the beginning I had one controller and one service like this :

Here is the service :

```
@Service
class StuffService {

    @Inject
    lateinit var environment : Environment

    fun doStuff() = [HERE FUNCTION CODE USING environment VARIABLE]

}
```

Here is the controller :

```
@RestController
class StuffController {

    @Inject
    lateinit var stuffService : StuffService

    @RequestMapping("/doStuff")
    fun doStuff() = stuffService.doStuff()

}
```

Unfortunately this give me this error when I start springboot :

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property environment has not been initialized
```

So I tried to inject via constructor :

```
@Service
class StuffService(val environment : Environment) {...}

@RestController
class StuffController(val stuffService: StuffService) {...}
```

With tha code it works ! I have no error.

I wonder what is the difference. I do not understand what happened. Can anyone help me to understand ?

Comment: Where are you accessing `environment`?

Comment: In the methode do stuff. I put [...] because it can be anything. I have replaced [...] with [HERE FUNCTION CODE USING environment VARIABLE]. I could be `environment.getProperty("my.property")`

Comment: Ok that seems all right... @Autowired probably does not make a difference?

Comment: No, it does not make a difference :/

Answer (score 0):

I tested this with the following versions:

```
kotlinVersion = '1.2.20'
springBootVersion = '2.0.1.RELEASE'
```

And `lateinit var` injection seems to be working fine in my case.

Here's an example project for your reference: https://github.com/jivimberg/lateinit

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are referencing the `environment` variable before it's even been initialized, that's why the exception.

It worked after the change. It was because the `environment` variable was initialized in the primary constructor. You may wonder how it worked without annotation. According to this [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/languages.html#kotlin)

> As of Spring Framework 4.3, classes with a single constructor have their parameters automatically autowired, that’s why there is no need for an explicit @Autowired constructor in the example shown above.